# How do i select the text of this li element but not the text of the span element within using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, css-selectors

Firstly I have this div element here:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 mx-auto" id="test-2-div">
                <h1>Test 2</h1>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">
                        List Item 1
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">3</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">
                        List Item 2
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">6</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">
                        List Item 3
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">9</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

Next, I am using this code to try to assert that the text in the second list item is "List Item 2"

```
def test2(self):
        listGroup = self.browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="test-2-div"]//ul[@class="list-group"]//li')
        secondListItemText = listGroup[1].text
        self.assertEqual(secondListItemText, "List Item 2")
```

However, it is returning

```
AssertionError: 'List Item 2 6' != 'List Item 2'
- List Item 2 6
?            --
+ List Item 2
```

Problem: I don't want to select the " 6" which is inside the span child of the li element and only the text directly in the li element. Anyone have a selector that will just return "List Item 2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this way:

```
def test2(self):
    listGroup = self.browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="test-2-div"]//ul[@class="list-group"]//li')
    secondListItemText = listGroup[1].text.strip().split('\n')[0]
    self.assertEqual(secondListItemText, "List Item 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
secondListItemText = listGroup[1].text.strip().split()[:3]
self.assertEqual(' '.join(secondListItemText), "List Item 2")
```

Comment: Your answer only contains code. I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Please review [answer]. It's not clear if this is an answer or and edit to the question.